# Proving cyclic subgroup of a finite group is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

> Prove that if $G$ is finite then $\forall a\in G$, $H:=\langle a\rangle$ is finite.

*Pf:* Let $G$ be a finite group with order $m$ and let $a \in G$. Suppose that $\langle a \rangle$ is infinite then we see that: $$\langle a\rangle \subset G$$

A contradiction! Since $\langle a \rangle$ is infinite while G is finite.

Any mistake? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Every subset of a finite set is finite.

Comment: So you are saying https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Subset_of_Finite_Set_is_Finite this works?

Comment: I guess you can also point out that $\langle a \rangle$ is a subset by closure of the operation. But yeah, there's not much to this proof.

Comment: Thanks for pointing closure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine.

Alternatively, $H:=\langle a\rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$, so, by Lagrange's Theorem, the order of $H$ divides the order of $G$, so is strictly less than or equal to the order of $G$. But $|G|$ is finite, so $|H|$ is finite.